# Order numeric values with WP_Query

Tags: wordpress, sorting, custom-post-type

I am trying to sort my custom post type numerically based on the numbers that are enter into an assigned MetaBox. The numbers I am entering has commas and are displaying in the database correctly. However, when the transactions are being displayed based on the below code it is listing all the first numbers together 1, 2 ,3, 4, 5, 6 with the lowest number first and the heights number last. The issue with this is when it comes to commas 6,000 is listed next to 6,000,000. What I am trying to do sis list the heights numbers (deal_amounts) first and the lowest amounts last. I am trying to sort them based on the whole amount not just the first number.

```
 $transaction = new WP_Query( array( 
                'post_type'         => 'transactions', 
                'paged'             => $paged, 
                'posts_per_page'    => 50,
                'orderby'           => array( 'meta_value' => 'ASC' ),
                'meta_key'          => 'deal_amount',
            ) );

        if ( $transaction->have_posts() ) :
```

Comment: you could save them without commas? just add them in the frontend?

Comment: That is what I just did and that seem to correct the issue.

Answer (score 0):

use meta_value_num for orderby in wp_query.

```
$args = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'transactions',
        'meta_key' => 'deal_amount',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Working example

```
 <?php
    $transaction = new WP_Query( array( 
        'post_type'         => 'transactions', 
        'paged'             => $paged, 
        'posts_per_page'    => 50,
        'orderby'           => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'ASC' ),
        'meta_key'          => 'deal_amount',
    ) );

if ( $transaction->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php 
while ( $transaction->have_posts() ) : $transaction->the_post();
    $deal_amount = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'deal_amount', true );
    $property_type = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'property_type', true );
    $property_size = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'property_size', true );
?>
<article class="col">

    <div class="trans-content">
        <?php the_title('<h3>', '</h3>'); ?>
        <?php echo '<h4>$' . number_format($deal_amount) . '</h4>'; ?>
        <?php echo esc_html($property_type); ?><br>
        <?php echo esc_html($property_size); ?><br>
        <?php $terms_as_text = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'loan-type', '', ', ', '' ) ; echo strip_tags($terms_as_text); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php edit_post_link('edit'); ?>
</article>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else : endif; ?>
```